# Is there a way to limit the upload rate of a particular application?

Tags: networking

I am looking for a way to set the limit on the upload rate for an application without limiting the entire machine.

The use case is the following:

The user (myself) creates a large file with the intention of uploading it to a video hosting site. However, the files are large and the internet connection is slow. So it can take hours (often tens of hours) to upload these files.

While the file uploads it is very difficult to use the internet. Due to the complete take ofver the upstream by the file upload.

The goal is to be able to limit the browser to 80% of the internet connection speed.

The perfect solution would be to be able to change the limit during the process of upload without having to restart anything or interrupt the upload itself. (Say the user wants to take the nap, bath, something to eat, etc, and is able to temporarily allow the upload to take the whole 100% of the ISP limit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install **trickle**

```
sudo apt-get install trickle
```

> Trickle is a voluntary, cooperative bandwidth shaper. it works
>   entirely in userland and is very easy to use.
>
> The most simple application is to limit the bandwidth usage of
>   programs.

here's a reference: http://www.tuxradar.com/content/control-your-bandwidth-trickle

Answer (score 1):

Yes so can use iptables to mark a packed based on the process (--pid-owner) and then use tc to limit the bandwidth.

Try reading [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-traffic-shaping-using-tc-to-control-http-traffic/) for example and see the HTTP outbound traffic shaping: just imagine doing the same but make the iptables mark rule apply to a PID instead of port 80!